# apache2: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long when visiting port 80?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-ssl

I have an Ubuntu 10 x64 server edition machine.  I got a second IP and configured /etc/network/interfaces like so (actual IPs and gateways removed):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto eth0
auto eth0:0

iface eth0 inet static
address [ my first IP ]
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway [ my first gateway ]

iface eth0:0 inet static
address [ my second IP ]
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway [ my second gateway ]
```

/etc/apache2/ports.conf:

```
Listen 80
NameVirtualHost [ my first IP ]:80
NameVirtualHost [ my second IP ]:80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
    NameVirtualHost [ my first IP - some site is running SSL successfully using it ]:443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.conf:

```
<VirtualHost [my second IP ]:80>
 ServerName mysite.com
 Include /var/www/mysite.com/djangoproject/apache/django.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Then when visiting `http://[mysite].com:80` or `http://[mysite].com`, I get:

```
An error occurred during a connection to [mysite].com.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
```

My guess is that the configuration file is not being picked up, and apache is therefore looking for the default-ssl file, which is not in conf-enabled.  If I were to configure that file properly, it seems I would successfully connect to whatever default directory is specified in the default-ssl file.   But I want to connect to my website.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I cleared my browser cache.  Then I re-visited the page and was able to connect correctly without a problem.  Looks like this was a case of user error.